# Different cardinality after each ALTER TABLE;

Tags: mysql, mariadb, indexes

[image: Different cardinality after each ALTER TABLE;]

There is no new entries in this table. Same error on 10.3.8-MariaDB and 10.2.6
What could cause that?

[image: Also have noticed that]

Also this is strange too.

Comment: Also looks like there is no such errors if i do the same on MySQL 5.6

Comment: The output from MySQL 5.6 would be helpful to see what you expect to see. The [InnoDB Persistent Statistics](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-persistent-statistics/) documentation does say that the value is only an estimation of rows and not an absolute measurement so slight variance would be expected.

Comment: @markusjm increasing of innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages helped to see normal Cardinality. Thanks for that link :)

Comment: @markusjm Please post it as an answer. Otherwise people still click on the question and waste time on it, as it is not marked *Answered*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the [InnoDB persistent statistics](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-persistent-statistics/) are only an estimate statistic, the values could be expected to change. Increasing [innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages) should improve the accuracy.